# Blazor - ApiController instantiated late, ignoring [Inject]

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

This is my controller (in a Blazor server app). It's used to handle a user uploading a file on a page.

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UploadController : ControllerBase
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte[]> UploadedFiles = new();

    [Inject]
    private ILogger<UploadController> Logger { get; set; } = default!;

    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public UploadController(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("UploadFile/{name}")]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile formFile, string name)
    {
```

This has been working fine for months. But now `Logger` is null.

Also, the object is not instantiated until I start the upload operation from a web page. I don't remember if that was always the case, but shouldn't controllers be created and listening when the server app starts? Or is it smart enough to only create them when needed?

I switched it to the following and this works. But I'm worried that I've got something wrong now. Any ideas?

```
private ILogger<UploadController> Logger { get; }

private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

public UploadController(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment, ILogger<UploadController> logger)
{
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    Logger = logger;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private ILogger<UploadController> Logger { get; }

private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

public UploadController(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment, ILogger<UploadController> logger)
{
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    Logger = logger;
}
```

is the correct way to inject dependencies into a controller.

The `[Inject]` attribute is used in Blazor Components (.razor).

I'm not sure how [Inject] has been working for you in the context of a controller before.  Perhaps, you just hadn't used the logger before so not encountered a Null Reference exception.  Or, less likely, you have some custom middleware that handles the [Inject] attribute!